# Using the same widget multiple times on the same html page

Tags: javascript, html, widget

I'm new to using html and widgets and having trouble using the same widget from https://coinmarketcap.com/widget/price-blocks/ multiple times on the same page:

**HTML - desired widget**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Coin Set 1</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/coinPriceBlock.js"></script>
<div id="coinmarketcap-widget-coin-price-block" coins="1,1027,825" currency="USD" theme="light" transparent="false" show-symbol-logo="true"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Coin Set 2</h1>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/coinPriceBlock.js"></script>
<div id="coinmarketcap-widget-coin-price-block" coins="1,1027,825" currency="USD" theme="light" transparent="false" show-symbol-logo="true"></div>
</div>
```

I can get the widget to work on different html pages.

Could someone explain why this wouldn't be working on the same page? And is it possible to use it multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript is not made for handling two widgets. Importing it multiple times won't change that.

A solution could be using iframes to separate the widgets.

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="800" height="400" src="widget.html"></iframe>
<iframe frameborder="0" width="800" height="400" src="widget.html"></iframe>
```

Place the widget code in `widget.html`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. the ```<div>...</div>``` below the script tag is what is calling the widget. So what I've tried is ```<iframe frameborder="0" width="800" height="400" type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/coinPriceBlock.js">
  <div id="coinmarketcap-widget-coin-price-block" coins="1,1027,825" currency="USD" theme="light" transparent="false" show-symbol-logo="true"></div>
</iframe>``` which doesn't work.

Comment: That ist not the way it was meant. Place my code from above in `index.html` file. Then create a second file called `widget.html` and place the `<div>...</div>` widget code there. Save both files to the same directory and open the index.html` in your browser.

Comment: Done what you've said but struggling to get the iframe to call the ```widget.html``` file. Both files are in the same directory but it looks like my app thinks it's a ```url```. I've tried the following:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="true" height="true" src="widget.html"></iframe>
<iframe frameborder="0" width="true" height="true" src="./widget.html"></iframe>
<iframe frameborder="0" width="true" height="true" src=".widget.html"></iframe>
<iframe frameborder="0" width="true" height="true" src="../widget.html"></iframe>```
and the absolute file path. FYI I'm using a mac

Comment: Sorry, can't rebuild the problem on my system. Works in all major browsers for me. Perhaps a hard reload of the page (with cache clearing) can help. 

`src="widget.html"` or `src="./widget.html"` are the only permitted values for this case.